# How do I map duplicates to keys, and map keys to duplicates in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, mapping

I have the following table with me:

```
Key Col  
ABC Dup1  
ACA Dup1  
ACA Dup2  
ECB Dup3  
ACD Dup2
```

I want to assign the first row value to key ACA in row 3 as Dup1(row2) and also change the value for ACD to Dup1 as ABC=ACA=ACD Following is the desired output:

```
Key Col  
ABC Dup1  
ACA Dup1  
ACA Dup1  
ECB Dup3  
ACD Dup1
```

I have tried my best to explain the problem but please feel free to ask further queries.

Comment: Can you explain why `ABC=ACA=ACD`?

Comment: Since row 1 and 2 have the same value "Dup1" therefore their key
 ABC = ACA    ------1
and similarly row 3 and 5 have same value "Dup2" therefore key
 ACA=ACD  ---------2
From 1 and 2 :
ABC=ACA=ACD


And hence same value to all 3 keys i.e. Dup1

Comment: Understood. Updated my answer. If it works, please do consider marking accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need two mappings to map duplicates to keys, and map keys to duplicates. Use `df.replace` to replace values.

```
m1 = dict(df.iloc[df.Col.drop_duplicates(keep='first').index].values[:, ::-1])
m2 = dict(df.iloc[df.Key.drop_duplicates(keep='first').index].values)
df.Col = df.Col.replace(m1).replace(m2)

df 
   Key   Col
0  ABC  Dup1
1  ACA  Dup1
2  ACA  Dup1
3  ECB  Dup3
4  ACD  Dup1
```